# Where is the Windows PowerShell 'env:' directory located?

Tags: windows, windows-11, environment-variables

In PowerShell, I can type the following command `cd env:` and the pwd becomes: `Env:\`.

I was wondering where this environment variable is in Windows 11. I looked under `Control Panel > Environment Variables`, but this doesn't appear to be the same information.

Can I navigate to this directory using file explorer, control panel, or another type of utility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the `Env` virtual drive is to manage environment variables. For example if you type `dir` it will list all environment variable names and their values. It's only visible in PowerShell.

You can read more on [devblogs.microsoft.com](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/learn-how-to-use-the-powershell-env-psdrive/).